# how to change username at cpanel?

Tags: cpanel, host

I rented a host with ***Cpanel*** service.
But the company I created them from has put an inappropriate username for Cpanel.
**I want to change the *username*.**
Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, I think you use Cpanel users to host your website.
you **can not** change your username with user accessibility.

So you have to ask your hosting provider to do it for you but keep it in your mind that changing the username of Cpanel has some consequences. as your database will not work anymore.

> At the moment you change the username of any cPanel account automatically all the things related to the username will be messed up. As we all know the WordPress database, MySQL Database has a default prefix username which is generated at the time of creating a database.
> So I will recommend that if you are using a MySQL database in your website then MySQL configuration should also be changed to the new account username accordingly and everywhere the things get changed.

Also take a look at this: [changing Cpanel username](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/change-cpanel-user-name.634621/)